# How to generate JHipster Api Gateway using bucket4j instead of cassandra

Tags: jhipster, yeoman-generator

JHipster has released support for creating api gateway using bucket4j and hazelcast with its 4.4.1 version.

But When I am trying to generate the api gateway using `yo jhipster`, There is no option present for bucket4j, And it also not mentioned in any jhipster documents that how to go with bucket4j.

I tried to create the gateway with no database but yml files for Cassandra are still there

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JHipster Gateway automatically integrates with bucket4j, usable with any database type. It is not a choice in the prompts.  See the JHipster [rate-limiting docs](https://jhipster.github.io/api-gateway/#rate_limiting) for more information on how to enable.

The Cassandra yml files should not have been copied over.  They were leftover from how rate-limiting previously worked.  This is fixed in [this Pull Request](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/5770) and will be in the next release.  You can remove those files if you have them and don't use Cassandra.

Comment: So I should go with no database, or what should I choose for 9th question?

Comment: That's up to you.  If you don't need a database in the gateway, you can choose No.  The bucket4j integration is separate from that choice